# Android Programming Button font does not change

Tags: android, fonts

I created the following button called

```
Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf");
loginButton.setTypeface(tf);
```

I made sure the font was under assets/fonts. The exact file name is:  /Users/**myusername**/Documents/GitHub/**appname**/app/src/main/assets/fonts/Lato-BoldItalic.ttf.

However, the font on the button still does not change. What could be the issue here?

Edit: extended code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId("###")
            .server("https://parseapi.back4app.com/")
            .clientKey("###")
            .enableLocalDataStore()
            .build()
    );

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Lato-Regular.ttf");
    loginButton.setTypeface(tf);

 more stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your font file on Assets folder then try to access like this

Create your assets folder in following tree structures

```
--\app
-----\src
----------\main
--------------\assets
```

then put your font file on inside assets folder

```
Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Lato-Regular.ttf");
loginButton.setTypeface(tf);
```

Hope it will help you..

Comment: I tried this, but it still does not work. :/ I'm not sure what other problems there could be.

Answer (score 0):

The font name in your code (`Lato-Regular.ttf`) is different than then name in your filesystem (`Lato-BoldItalic.ttf`).

Also, Android cannot handle every possible font. In those cases, it quietly fails and defaults to the regular font. You may need to experiment with other fonts.

Comment: I have both fonts in the assets folder, and I just changed it to BoldItalic so the change would clearer in case my eyes are just bad. I'll try a different font and see if that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have said from the folder it is `Lato-BoldItalic.ttf` while you have set `fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf`. Edit your code! Set the required font you have added to your project.